# Reductions to the MAX-3-DCC Problem

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, combinatorial-optimization

I am currently working on the **Max-3-DCC** problem that asks for the heaviest vertex-disjoint cycle cover of weighted directed graphs.

The problem has been reduced to 3-SAT in 1979 by L. Valiant in his article on [The Complexity of Calculating the Permanent](http://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Eaf1p/Teaching/MCC17/Papers/permanent.pdf).

Later, around 2005 B. Manthey proved the **APX-hard**ness of the problem in [On Approximating Restricted Cycle Covers](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0504038), followed by a series of articles on related problems of calculating restricted cycle covers.

I recently had new ideas for calculating Max-3-DCCs and was looking for benchmark instances similar to those for TSP, however neither a related question on cs.stackexchange https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/35522/benchmark-instances-for-directed-3-cycle-cover?noredirect=1#comment67646_35522 nor extensively searching the internet brought about anything directly in that direction.
I have the impression that the Max-3-DCC is the Cinderella of NP complete problems; it is almost never "invited" to lists of such problems and hardly the subject of interest, expressed as publications.

I therefore put my hopes in getting access to benchmark instances via "simple" reductions from other NP complete problems:

> **Question:**
>
> which NP complete optimization problems, **for which collections of freely accessible benchmark instances are available**,  can be transformed to Max-3-DCC and back in time linear in the size of the instance, which should be possible because most of Karp's problems are class **NLIN** according to [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0606080).
> My *most wanted* are of course the problems in Karp's list of 21, most prominently TSP and vertex-cover.

for clarification:   
instances qualify as benchmarks for me only if their optimal solution is known and if known heuristics will fail to report it. Instances with best *known* solutions are also acceptable.  
Apart from that the data should be freely accessible.