# Gadgets that reduce NP hard problems to the MAX-3-DCC Problem

Tags: combinatorial-optimization

A while ago I had asked for benchmark instance for the  [MAX-3-DCC Problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365916/reductions-to-the-max-3-dcc-problem) but did not receive any feedback.
This question is a follow up aimed at concrete examples of reductions of NP hard problems to the MAX-3-DCC problem:

**Question:**

what are **examples of gadgets** that transform an instances of NP hard problems to a weighted digraph with anti-parallel arcs such that the optimal unrestricted vertex-disjoint directed cycle cover can contain anti-parallel arcs but if it does, the optimal solution to the original problem can't be recovered from it, i.e.
The optimal solution to the original problem can only be recovered from the optimal directed vertex disjoint cycle covers restricted to cycles with at least three arcs.